# how to get rid of ul li ie 6 bullet point highlighting

Tags: css

I have the following html....

```
    <div id="modern-ticker" class="modern-ticker mt-round">
        <div class="mt-label" class="mt-label">NEWS:</div>
        <div id="mt-news" class="mt-news">
            <ul>                    
                <li><a class="green" href="#" target="_self">News 1 News 1News 1News </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In firefox and chrome my styles look good...

[image]

But in ie6 i get a bit of highlighting on the bullet point image. If you look carefully at the image below you will see a bit of blu in the background over the green light image.

[image]

I was just wondering if anyone could help me with how I could get rid of this. Here is what my styles look like...

```
.mt-news li {
    margin-left: 0.5em !important;
    line-height: 18px !important;
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.mt-news a.green {
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
    background-image: url("../images/green.png") !important;
    color: #505050;
    padding: 8px 0 0 35px !important;
    background-position: left top !important;
}
```

thanks

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/png-hack-for-ie-6/

Comment: IE6 doesn't support transparent image.

Comment: [Why do you need support for IE6?](http://www.modern.ie/ie6countdown) Also, IE6 doesn't support `display:inline-block`.

Comment: @vucko there are still few peoples in word who love IE6 still.

Comment: @KheemaPandey possibly around 10-20 people.

Answer (score 2):

In IE6 to fix this bug you can use AlphaImageLoader filter.

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.png', sizingMethod='scale');
```

There are other method to solve it by some javascript code. but this seems the simple solution.

Also you can use the IE conditional statement.

```
<!--[if gte IE 5]>  
<style type="text/css">  
  img {  
  background:none;  
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.png' ,sizingMethod='scale');  
  }  
</style>  
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I am really struggling to make your solution work for me. So far I cannot get rid of the ugly grey / blue square around my image. Going to update my question to show you what I have tried...